# fetching image from gallery to my application and store in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, gallery

I am new to developing Android applications. Can anyone help me in how to open the gallery application from my application and select only one image from gallery.

Also, how do I store that selected picture in an SQLite database?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setType("image/*");
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Picture"),IMAGE);
```

then in the on Activity result

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    try {

                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
                   //Cancelled
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can convert the image to Base64 encoded string format and store it in the database.